# Accessing other group_by groups with summarize()

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, summarize

I have a data frame with columns genes, the region of the chromosome they belong to, the cell line the gene expression was measured from, and the gene's expression level in that cell line -- it looks basically something like this:

```
gene    region    cell_line    expression
A       X         Joe          1
B       X         Joe          2 
C       Y         Joe          2
D       Z         Joe          3
E       Z         Joe          0
A       X         Claire       2
B       X         Claire       1
C       Y         Claire       3
D       Z         Claire       3
E       Z         Claire       1
```

What I want to do is, for each cell line, calculate the mean, standard deviation, etc. for a chromosomal region of all genes NOT in the given region. So for region X of Joe, for example, I want the output "summarize()" row to show the mean of the expression for all genes NOT in Joe's X (i.e. genes C, D, E of Joe).

So the output looks something like:

```
region    cell_line     mean_other    standard_deviation_other   
X         Joe           1.67          some number
Y         Joe           1.5           some number
Z         Joe           1.67          some number
X         Claire        2.33          some number
Y         Claire        2.33          some number
Z         Claire        2             some number
```

My idea would be to do the following, except I have no clue on how to get summarize to manipulate groups outside of the one it's "operating on" at a given time.

```
df %>% group_by(region, cell_line) %>% 
 summarize(mean_other = mean(expression of cell lines not in this group),
           standard_deviation_other = var(expression of cell lines not in this group)
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use the new `dplyr::group_modify()` to easily apply a function across groups, which takes each group as a data frame. Then we can just use `dplyr::anti_join()` on the original data frame and apply whatever you wanted in your summarize.

Using `mtcars`:

```r
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  group_modify(~anti_join(mtcars, .) %>%
                 summarize(disp_m = mean(disp),
                           disp_sd = sd(disp)))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#> # Groups:   cyl [3]
#>     cyl disp_m disp_sd
#>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1     4   297.   101. 
#> 2     6   244.   136. 
#> 3     8   136.    50.7
```

And checking for the first group with `cyl == 4`:

```r
mtcars %>%
  filter(cyl != 4) %>%
  summarize(disp_m = mean(disp),
            disp_sd = sd(disp))
#>     disp_m  disp_sd
#> 1 296.5048 101.1434
```

On your `df`, it should look like this:

```r
df %>%
  group_by(region, cell_line) %>%
  group_modify(~anti_join(df, .) %>%
               summarize(mean_other = mean(expression),
                         sd_other = var(expression)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! There's just one thing I should have detailed more carefully in my draft code that I don't think this accomplishes -- I'd want mean_other and sd_other to be calculated from other regions within the _same_ cell line, and, while group_modify and anti_join are very helpful, I don't really see how to use them to get past this specific roadblock